# Does the functor $\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{Z}(\mathcal{C})$ have adjoints?

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, braided-tensor-categories

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a braided monoidal category. We have a canonical functor $\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{Z}(\mathcal{C})$ from $\mathcal{C}$ to the Drinfeld center $\mathcal{Z}(\mathcal{C})$ sending an object $V$ in $\mathcal{C}$ to $(V,c_{V,\,\_})$. Here, $c$ is the braiding in $\mathcal{C}$.

When does this functor admit left/right adjoints, and how do they look like? You are free to assume as much as you want on the category $\mathcal{C}$ (abelian, finite, factorizable, etc).

Comment: Abstractly: C is an E_2-monoidal category, so by the universal property of the Drinfeld center (as the Hochschild cohomology of C, at least if one works in the derived setting), the identity C -> C factors through the canonical functor Z(C) -> C. (The functor Z(C) -> C sends a pair (x, phi) to x.)

Comment: @skd Sure, but does this mean that the forgetful functor Z(C) -> C is an adjoint of the above? Sorry, maybe this is trivial..

Comment: No, the forgetful functor Z(C) --> C is defined even when C is not braided, it has a right adjoint (often called induction) which again doesn't depend on the braiding.  For example, it sends 1 to $\bigoplus_x x \otimes x*$ in the semisimple case (and a "canonical coend" in general).  It's adjoint can't be the inclusion C --> Z(C) which depends on the braiding for its construction.

Comment: @Noah Snyder Thx, that's what I thought. I wasn't sure what skd was trying to tell me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short answer**: Yes, it can possibly have an adjoint.

**Longer answer**:
Assume that $\mathcal{C}$ is rigid, and that the coend $L = \int^{X \in \mathcal{C}} X^* \otimes X$ exists.
It is a coalgebra.
Your assumptions on $\mathcal{C}$ were that it is braided, and in that case, it is well-known that $L$ is even a bialgebra.
Moreover, we know that ${}_L\mathcal{C} = \mathcal{Z}(\mathcal{C})$, i.e. the center of $\mathcal{C}$ is isomorphic to the category of modules over $L$.

Under this isomorphism, your "free central object" $(V, c_{V, -})$ is sent to the trivial $L$-module on $V$, i.e. the action is $\varepsilon \otimes V \colon L \otimes V \to V$, where $\varepsilon \colon L \to 1$ is the counit of $L$.
It is an algebra morphism.
Thus, walking everything through the isomorphisms, the inclusion functor can actually be interpreted as the pullback functor
\begin{align}
  \varepsilon^* \colon {}_1\mathcal{C} = \mathcal{C} \to {}_L\mathcal{C}
\ .
\end{align}
A sufficient condition for pullbacks along algebra morphisms to have adjoints was identified in [my answer to my own question over on M.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4362375/100833).

Translating to our situtation, $\varepsilon^*$ has a left adjoint if $\mathcal{C}$ has coequalizers and $L$ is coflat (i.e. $L \otimes - $ preserves coequalizers).
Then the left adjoint sends an $L$-module $(V, r)$ to the coequalizer of
$$
r,\ \varepsilon \otimes id_V \colon L \otimes V \to V
\ .
$$

So for a particular situation where it works:
take $\mathcal{C}$ to be a braided finite tensor category in the sense of EGNO.
Then in particular, $\mathcal{C}$ is abelian, so it has coequalizers, and the tensor product is exact, so every object is coflat.
Moreover, it's well-known that for these kinds of categories, the coend $L$ indeed does exist.